# Two Bootstrap Modals to edit two different files content

Tags: php, if-statement, twitter-bootstrap-3

First let me start by saying I know this is going to be a really basic question. I am new to PHP and struggling a little with this task.

**Intro:**
I am making a little app on a local WAMP server to manage a basic client database and also manage all my VHOST enntries for development. I know there are security issues with editing Windows Hosts file as I'm about to request but this will be strictly a local site.

I have the following PHP

```
<?php include 'template-parts/header.php' /** calling of header(to make it uniform in all template file) **/?>  

<div class="container home">
    <h3> Delete </h3>



    <div class="btn-group">
            <button data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="hostsedit" data-target="#modalhost"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Edit Windows Host File</button>
            <button data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="vhostsedit" data-target="#modalvhost"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Edit VHOST.conf</button>
    </div>


    <?php

        // configuration
        $url = 'delete.php';
        $file = 'C:/Windows/System32/Drivers/etc/hosts';

        // check if form has been submitted
        if (isset($_POST['text']))
        {
        // save the text contents
        file_put_contents($file, $_POST['text']);

        // redirect to form again
        header(sprintf('Location: %s', $url));
        printf('<a href="%s">Moved</a>.', htmlspecialchars($url));
        exit();
    }

    // read the textfile
    $text = file_get_contents($file);   
    ?>


    <!-- Modal 1 -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalhost" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Host File Entry</h4>
            </div><!-- /modal-header -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                            <!-- HTML form -->
                            <form action="" method="post">
                                <textarea name="text" class="form-control" rows="15"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($text) ?></textarea><br />
                                <p><strong>NOTE:</strong> Ensure only lines similar to <kbd>127.0.0.1 www.dev.xxxxx</kbd> are deleted</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                        
            </div><!-- /modal-body -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div> 
            </form>
        </div> <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div> <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div> <!-- /.modal -->


<!-- Modal 2 --> 
<div class="modal fade" id="modalvhost" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Delete VHOST File Entry</h4>
            </div><!-- /modal-header -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                            <!-- HTML form -->
                            <form action="" method="post">
                                <textarea name="text" class="form-control" rows="15"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($text) ?></textarea><br />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                        
            </div><!-- /modal-body -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div> 
            </form>
        </div> <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div> <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div> <!-- /.modal -->
</div>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The first modal works perfectly, I click the button `<button data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="hostsedit" data-target="#modalhost"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Edit Windows Host File</button>` and this opens up the Bootstrap Modal, presents the Windows Host file within the textarea and allows me to add and delete at will, I click the modal's save button and it works.

**The question** I need to acheive this same action with the second modal window however this one needs would need to edit `C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf'`.

I simply don't know how to duplicate the first correctly working PHP to now also work with the VHOST editing requirement.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Hi Neal, I tried putting your solution into place and got some errors that I'm not entirely sure how to get past...

I currently have this in my PHP file:

```
<div class="container home">
<h3> Delete </h3>



<div class="btn-group">
        <button data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="hostsedit" data-target="#modalhost"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Edit Windows Host File</button>
        <button data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="vhostsedit" data-target="#modalvhost"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Edit VHOST.conf</button>
</div>


<?php
// check if form has been submitted
if (!empty($_POST['hostinput'])){ //i prefer to use empty rather than isset you can read about it

    // configuration
    $url = 'delete.php';
    $file = 'C:/Windows/System32/Drivers/etc/hosts';

    // check if form has been submitted
    if (isset($_POST['hostinput']))
    {
    // save the text contents
    file_put_contents($file, $_POST['hostinput']);

    // redirect to form again
    header(sprintf('Location: %s', $url));
    printf('<a href="%s">Moved</a>.', htmlspecialchars($url));
    exit();
    }
    // read the textfile
    $text = file_get_contents($file);  
}
else if(!empty($_POST['vhostinput'])){
    // configuration
    $url = 'delete.php';
    $file = 'C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf';

    // check if form has been submitted
    if (isset($_POST['vhostinput']))
    {
    // save the text contents
    file_put_contents($file, $_POST['vhostinput']);

    // redirect to form again
    header(sprintf('Location: %s', $url));
    printf('<a href="%s">Moved</a>.', htmlspecialchars($url));
    exit();
    }
    // read the textfile
    $text = file_get_contents($file);  
}


?>


<!-- Modal 1 -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalhost" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Host File Entry</h4>
        </div><!-- /modal-header -->
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                        <!-- HTML form -->
                        <form action="" method="post">
                            <textarea id="hostinput" name="hostinput" class="form-control" rows="15"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($text) ?></textarea><br />
                            <p><strong>NOTE:</strong> Ensure only lines similar to <kbd>127.0.0.1 www.dev.xxxxx</kbd> are deleted</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>                        
        </div><!-- /modal-body -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div> 
        </form>
    </div> <!-- /.modal-content -->
</div> <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

```
<!-- Modal 2 --> 
<div class="modal fade" id="modalvhost" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Delete VHOST File Entry</h4>
            </div><!-- /modal-header -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                             <!-- HTML form -->
                             <form action="" method="post">
                                 <textarea id="vhostinput" name="vhostinput" class="form-control" rows="15"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($text) ?></textarea><br />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                        
            </div><!-- /modal-body -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
             </div> 
            </form>
        </div> <!-- /.modal-content -->
     </div> <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div> <!-- /.modal -->
</div>
```

And the error I get on the second call is:
    Notice: Undefined variable: text in C:\Users\xxx\xxx\xxx\devlogs\delete.php on line 116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-target="#myModal1" data-toggle="modal" type="button"> Edit</button>  <!-- first button for the first modal-->

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-target="#myModalA1" data-toggle="modal" type="button"> Comment</button>  <!-- second button for the second modal-->

<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
<div id="myModalA1" class="modal" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
```

This code seems similar to your code but im not too sure if there is some differences (this one i am 100% sure that its working perfectly fine).

Now for your question where you want to submit the form for the second modal. There are many ways to handle this ( like using ajax and saving everything without the need of forms or refreshing the page.) but since you said you are new to php and you already started in this way so... what i can suggest is that....

1) for every input you have you must give it an id and name. so your inputs should look like this (you can set the same name and id for the same field but every field must be unique):

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="15" id="hostinput" name="hostinput"></textarea>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="15" id="vhostinput" name="vhostinput"></textarea>
```

2)Then in your php code you type:

```
// check if form has been submitted
    if (!empty($_POST['hostinput'])){ //i prefer to use empty rather than isset you can read about it

    // save the text contents
    file_put_contents($file, $_POST['text']);

    // redirect to form again
    header(sprintf('Location: %s', $url));
    printf('<a href="%s">Moved</a>.', htmlspecialchars($url));
    exit();
}
esleif(!empty($_POST['vhostinput'])){
//SAVE THE VHOST
}
```

This way what you are doing is whenever a submit button pressed you try and check the two values and save them again both of them.

WARNING: this method is a bit dangerous.... lets say that the user edited the first text but then he clicked cancel.... then edited the second text then he clicked submit for the second text.... you will actually save both of them....

The way i usually do this is by using javascript and ajax so i dont have to refresh the page also...

Hope i helped....

Comment: Hi Neal, I had some issues with your solution... I've pasted my code in the edit above. I seem to be seriously out of my depth. I'm really sorry, I am researching the errors but can't seem to get anywhere.

Comment: Remove the if(!empty.....) line and keep everything else the same.... and let me know what will happen and if there is any error please show me whats written not just the line number....

Comment: Hi Neal, thank you so much for taking the time... When I remove the if(!empty...) lines, there are no errors at all presented however both buttons only open the last file that appears in the PHP, in this case the VHOSTS file. Almost as if the last half that calls the VHOSTS file supersedes the first half trying to call the HOST file.